# POSTGIS unwanted results with St_INTERSECTS and ST_CROSSES

Tags: postgis

I got a table l_t_troncon, with a geom column LINESTRING. It represents a Path.

Now, I want to detect if a path intersects others.

Sometimes, when I use ST_INTERSECTS, it says False.
Whereas, in same query, ST_DISTANCE says 0 and ST_INTERSECTION says there is  intersection(s).

On a map, there is an intersection.

It's a join on table itself, SRID are same.
 and geom column is a geometry (not geography).

I don't know why this happens.
I use postgresql 9.4 and postgis 2.1.8 from official postgresql APT repo.

Any explanation ?

my query :

```
SELECT lt2.id,
   ST_DISTANCE(lt.geom, lt2.geom) as DIS,
   ST_SRID(lt.geom) as SRID,
   ST_ASTEXT(lt.geom) as GEOM1,
   ST_ASTEXT(lt2.geom) as GEOM2,
   ST_CROSSES(lt.geom, lt2.geom) as CROSSES,
   ST_INTERSECTS(lt.geom, lt2.geom) as INTERSECTS,
   ST_DWITHIN(lt.geom, lt2.geom, 0) as DWITHIN,
   ST_EQUALS(ST_ClosestPoint(lt.geom, lt2.geom), ST_ClosestPoint(lt2.geom, lt.geom)) as POINTS_EQUALS,
   ST_ASTEXT(ST_INTERSECTION(lt.geom, lt2.geom)) as INTERSECTION
FROM l_t_troncon lt 
JOIN l_t_troncon lt2 ON lt.id != lt2.id
WHERE lt.id = 3253 ORDER BY DIS ASC;
```

results:

```
ID   DIS              SRID GEOM1                                                                           GEOM2                                                                           CROSSES INTERSECTS DWITHIN POINTS_EQUALS INTERSECTION

3251 0                2154 LINESTRING(1090785.76652617 6536888.19328297,1090833.26031043 6536868.26841502) LINESTRING(1090552.31321667 6538203.74023832,1090799.01544745 6536813.53348014) f       f          t       t             POINT(1090785.76652617 6536888.19328297)
3252 52.7247742247967 2154 LINESTRING(1090785.76652617 6536888.19328297,1090833.26031043 6536868.26841502) LINESTRING(1090799.01544745 6536813.53348014,1097373.76929105 6537183.45894039) f       f          f       f             GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
3248 63.7211646996764 2154 LINESTRING(1090785.76652617 6536888.19328297,1090833.26031043 6536868.26841502) LINESTRING(1083213.56795189 6536386.7418127,1090799.01544745 6536813.53348014)  f       f          f       f             GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

If I try just on LINESTRINGS:

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(1090785.76652617 6536888.19328297,1090833.26031043 6536868.26841502)', 2154),
                   ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(1090552.31321667 6538203.74023832,1090799.01544745 6536813.53348014)', 2154))
```

result is 4.06621238136966e-09

```
SELECT ST_ASTEXT(ST_INTERSECTION(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(1090785.76652617 6536888.19328297,1090833.26031043 6536868.26841502)', 2154),
                                 ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('LINESTRING(1090552.31321667 6538203.74023832,1090799.01544745 6536813.53348014)', 2154)))
```

result is GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY

Issue seems to be only on the first result (ID 3251). Good results on both others

Comment: tested with postgis 2.2.0 and 2.3.0dev.

Comment: Add to the question the data you are using. I.e. modify the query to show also the input geometries: `SELECT lt2.id,lt1.geom AS geom1, lt2.geom AS geom2...`

Comment: On my system the two lines have a distance of 4.06621238136966e-09. It seems to be a rounding issue

Comment: ok, see that when I try a ST_DISTANCE on both linestrings. But now question is where is the rounding issue ? I don't round anything, just a ST_DISTANCE on two objects. Index are clean